# tinymce text editor with formcollection serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, tinymce

Can anyone tell me how can I serialize tinymce text editor content with formcollection.serialize method??
 I tried using :

```js
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});


$("#btnEmail").click(function () {          
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Email")',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#emailform').serialize(),// + "&emailContent=emailContent",
        // data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
});
```

```html
<textarea name="emailContent" id="emailContent" style="width: 100%" ></textarea>
```

public ActionResult Email(FormCollection data)
        {
            foreach (var key in data.AllKeys)
            {
                var value = data[key];
            }
            string Content = data["emailContent"];
        }

Comment: What problem are you having? What errors are you getting?

Comment: First of all thanks for your response...... actually I don't get any error but problem is that Formcollection parameter of my controller can't render the content of the textarea........ but all other control's value are passing fine through Formcollection parameter. Thanks

Comment: What makes you think the value of the textarea is not being serialized?

Comment: Then show you controller method and the model.

Comment: `FormCollection`? Seriously? Use a model, bind to the model and post back the model.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly what is the problem of formcollection ? I want to learn because I am a newbe......

Comment: Do not use form collection. Go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics of MVC.

Comment: ok thanks a lot and I must do it. But I have completed my whole project using Formcollection and at the end of my project I just stuck with this tinyMCE editor and if I fail than I have to do my whole project from the first. If you have any idea about this problem it will be a great help for me. I think you will understand my situation, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying at last I have solved  the issue perfectly. There were two things absent from my code: 1. form submission before ajax call and 2. adding an attribute [Validateinput(false)] just above my controller. Here is the final solution below:

```
   // Controller
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Email(FormCollection data)
    {
        foreach (var key in data.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = data[key];
        }
       string Content = data["emailContent"];
    }
```

Javascript:

```
   tinyMCE.init({
        selector: "textarea"           

    });
```

//========Email Button

```
     $("#btnEmail").click(function () {
         tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
        $('#emailform').submit();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Email")',
            type: "POST",

            data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true

        });
    });

//========= HTML
<textarea name="emailContent" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```